# How to I change a value of a cell in an Excel worksheet from MS Access using VBA?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

How to I change a value of a cell in an Excel worksheet from MS Access using VBA? Thanks!

```
            ....
            Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

            objApp.Visible = True
            Set wb = objApp.Workbooks.Open("fileHere.xls", True, False)

            'Below does not work (Title is in cell A1):
            wb.Sheets(1).Rows(1).Insert ("Replace Title Here")
            ....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "Replace Title Here"
```